# Why can't i maintain aspect ratio with max height value?

Tags: css, image, height, width, aspect-ratio

I use a class for my portrait and landscape images. All my landscape images have the same size of 1400x1000px (700x500px 5K retina proof). And i want the portrait images always to be 700px in height and width set to auto, but it doesn't seem to work that way. Why?

```
.size-m { /* project image portrait */
  max-height: 700px;
  width: auto;
 }

.size-xl { /* project image landscape */
 max-width: 700px;
 height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding, but this appears to be working fine in these jsfiddles:

[landscape](https://jsfiddle.net/zg1ogppp/1/)

```
img {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: auto;
}
```

[portrait](https://jsfiddle.net/zg1ogppp/2/)

```
img {
  max-height: 700px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it has to do with my css layout a class interferes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to your classes. That should do the trick.